# How to fix name sorter? NoSuchElementFound error...?

Tags: java, sorting, debugging

I wrote name sorting program designed to sort a list of names (duh) and give index value of my name. For some reason it compiles fine but says there's something wrong with 'maleNames[i] = nameScan.nextLine();" and returns this message:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at NameSorter.main(NameSorter.java:14)
```

Any ideas or fixes? Thanks in advance!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NameSorter
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        String [] maleNames = new String[1220];
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream("sorted_male_names.txt");

        Scanner nameScan = new Scanner(new File("common_male_names.txt"));

        for (int i = 0; i < maleNames.length; i++)
        {
            maleNames[i] = nameScan.nextLine();
        }

        bubbleSort(maleNames);

        for (int i = 0; i < maleNames.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(maleNames[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < maleNames.length; i++)
        {
            String currentName = maleNames[i];
            ps.println(currentName);
        }

        System.out.println(linearSearch(maleNames, "zander"));
    }

    public static boolean isSorted(String[] arr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length -1; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i].compareTo(arr[i+1]) > 0)
                return false;
            }
        return true;
    }

    public static void swapElements(String[] arr, int index1, int index2)
    {
        String tempValue = arr[index1];
        arr[index1] = arr[index2];
        arr[index2] = tempValue;
    }

    public static void bubbleSort(String[] arr)
    {
        while(isSorted(arr) == false) // while(!isSorted(arr)) 
        {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i].compareTo(arr[i+1]) > 0)
            swapElements(arr, i, i+1);
        }
        }
    }

    public static int linearSearch(String[] arr, String name)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i > arr.length; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i].equals(name))
            return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void printArray(int[] arr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post up your common_male_names.txt file content?

Comment: Won't let me because it's too big. It's basically a long list of unordered names.

Comment: are they listed in horizontal way?

Comment: Can you post the few last line?

Comment: Here's some, one name per line: bernard
mario
leroy
francisco
marcus
micheal
theodore
clifford
miguel
oscar
jay
jim
tom
calvin
alex
jon
ronnie
bill
lloyd
tommy
leon
derek
warren
darrell
jerome
floyd
leo
alvin
tim
wesley
gordon
dean
greg
jorge
dustin
pedro
derrick
dan
lewis
zachary

Comment: the answer you have is completely right, so read it and apply what it says

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < maleNames.length; i++) {
        maleNames[i] = nameScan.nextLine();
}
```

Assumes there are `maleNames.length` elements in the file (1220 in this case) if there are fewer than that you will get a `NoSuchElementException`

A better way would be to use the Scanner's `hasNextLine()` method and a `List<String>`

```
List<String> maleNames = new ArrayList<>();

while(nameScan.hasNextLine()) { 
    maleNames.add(nameScan.nextLine());
}
```

This would allow for a name file of any length, so long as its correctly formatted, and avoids your exception.

Comment: add this link http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-solve-javautilnosuchelementexcep.html if the op wants to read more